# c# linq exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, exception

When I run a linq query I get back the results only when an item can be found; if no items are found, it is throwing an exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How do I not throw this exception? I want only to return a result even if it is empty.

```
var id = db.table.Where(a => a.item == passed_item).FirstOrDefault().id;
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This method, `FirstOrDefault`, will return `null`, if  an object not been found. Hence, if you try to read the value of `id`, then an exception will be thrown.

One way to avoid this is the following:

```
// I suppose that the id you want to read is an int.
// If it isn't, please change the code correspondingly. 
int id;

// Try to get the record.
var record = db.table.Where(a => a.item == passed_item)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

// If you find the record you are looking for, then read it's id.
if(record != null) 
{
    id = record.id;
}
```

**Update**

Another option it would be to follow that `DavidG` suggested in his comment:

```
var record = db.Table.FirstOrDefault(a => a.item == passed_item);
```

and the next step is the same.

Comment: Or potentially `db.Table.FirstOrDefault(a => a.item == passed_item)`

Comment: @DavidG you are correct. I copied and pasted David's code and I didn't pay attention on this. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Or 1 line `var id = (db.table.FirstOrDefault(a => a.item == passed_item))?.id;`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Null-conditional operator instead:

```
int? id = db.table.Where(a => a.item == passed_item).FirstOrDefault()?.id;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = (from a in db.table
      where a.item == passed_item
      select a.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will ensure that it only tries to dereference `id` when something is found.  Other wise, `id` will be assigned whatever the default value for the `id` property is (null or zero)

Comment: good answer! This only select the ID field from the database - and are therefor more efficient

Answer (score 1):

I saw the cause in null being one of the values.

```
SImageName = (Users.SImageName != null ? Users.SImageName : "User.png")
```

**Check in your data there is no NULL value**

```
                var userlist = (from Users in _context.TbUsersInfos
                            join Orgs in _context.TbBaseOrgs
                               on Users.NOrgCode equals Orgs.NCode
                            where
                               Users.NOrgCode == 1
                            orderby
                               Users.NUserCode
                            select new
                            {
                                NUserCode = Users.NUserCode.ToString(),
                                SImageName = (Users.SImageName != null ? Users.SImageName : "User.png"),
                            }).ToList();
```